# How do I convert a Python Array to a SymPy Matrix to calculate the determinant?

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, matrix, sympy

I managed to create a python array of this kind :

```
MainMatrix=[[0 for x in range(n)] for y in range(n)]
```

(And I changed some values in the Matrix)

Now, I want to know if it is possible to convert this to a SymPy Matrix so that I may calculate the determinant (given all values in the MainMatrix aren't integers and some are SymPy Symbols). I want something of this kind :

```
M=Matrix([MainMatrix])          #Conversion of Array to SymPy Matrix
M.det()                         #Computation of Determinant of the Matrix
```

(Yes, I am aware that the first line doesn't work, but I just put it to show my intention)

A solution to this conversion, or any other alternative to find the determinant of the MainMatrix (keeping in mind that all entries aren't integers and some are SymPy Symbols) would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Your `MainMatrix` is already in the correct form. You just need to pass it to `sympy.Matrix`.

```
M = Matrix(MainMatrix)
```

Answer (score 1):

Acording to the example of the documentation, Is just simple as doing:

```
from sympy import *
import math

n=3

n_atoms=8

MainMatrix=Matrix([[0 for x in range(n)] for y in range(n)])

KappaMatrix=Matrix([0 for x in range(n-1)])

MassMatrix=Matrix([0 for x in range(n)])

Kappa=3

ka_by_pi=4

for i in range(1,n):

    KappaMatrix[i-1]=3

for i in range(1,n+1):

    MassMatrix[i-1]=3

for i in range(2,n):

    MainMatrix[i-1]= -KappaMatrix[i-2]/MassMatrix[i-1]

    MainMatrix[i-1]= (KappaMatrix[i-2] + KappaMatrix[i-1])/MassMatrix[i-1]

    MainMatrix[i-1]= -KappaMatrix[i-1]/MassMatrix[i-1]

    MainMatrix[0]=(KappaMatrix[0]+Kappa)/MassMatrix[0]

    MainMatrix[0]=-(KappaMatrix[0])/MassMatrix[0]

    i=symbols('i')

    MainMatrix[0]= -(Kappa/MassMatrix[0])*(math.cos(math.pi*ka_by_pi)+(i*math.sin(math.pi*ka_by_pi)))

    MainMatrix[n-1]= -(Kappa/MassMatrix[n-1])*(math.cos(math.pi*ka_by_pi)-(i*math.sin(math.pi*ka_by_pi)))

    MainMatrix[n-1]=-(KappaMatrix[n-2])/MassMatrix[n-1]

    MainMatrix[n-1]=(KappaMatrix[n-2]+Kappa)/MassMatrix[n-1]

    t=symbols('t')

for j in range(0,n_atoms):
    MainMatrix[j]=MainMatrix[j]-(t**2)

print(MainMatrix)
```

Comment: If I do that, and then try to assign/change a value in the MainMatrix using
MainMatrix[i-1][i]=2    #JustAnExample
Then it is giving me an error:
TypeError: 'Zero' object does not support item assignment
How do I get through this?

Comment: @Raj Could you add in the question the example with all the details you can? because it worked for me, but maybe I'm missing something

Comment: @Raj I mean, the matrix you want to construct

Comment: Here is the code regarding the matrix construct (didn't share as it was too long):

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzMBW_NtVc2abEMyZkYzc2xENkE


.

Comment: @Raj, that's the closer aproach I could offer, given the data I had, so I hope it helped you, I updated the answer, look that you only can call one column, so you can do just: MainMatrix[1] , and not MainMatrix[1][0]